# AngularJS Expression inside Google Analytics Event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics

I would like to add some google analytics events to items inside my ng-repeat. The events fire, i can seen them in the real time event overview, however i get it like this on GA (the actual expression):

Event Category   / Event Action  / Event Label
Click CD Details / {{cd.cdname}} / {{cd.code}}

Now this is the string i use:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Click CD details', '{{cd.cdname}}', '{{cd.code})';
```

How would i be able to change this so GA and get the right information?

Comment: Have you looked at using http://angulartics.github.io/ ? Based on what you have here, you're probably going to have to write your own directive if you're not using a 3rd party lib to handle it (like the link).  You'll want to use the `$compile` service too most likely.

Comment: Should the {{variables}} be quoted? I don't think that's correct syntax.

Comment: without the quote is get the error: "Expected identifier, string or number"

Comment: hi jusopi, the thirdparty is a bit much i guess since i only need it in this case on one location in the complete project

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I took a deeper look on this one.

It seems like GA is out of the scope so AngularJS can't work inside it. If you don't want to use [Angularytics](https://github.com/mgonto/angularytics), you should include it in your app.

I assume it's a click event, but you can take it anywhere you want.

```
<body ng-app="windowExample">
  <script>
  angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.greeting = 'Hello, World!';
      $scope.doGreeting = function(greeting) {
        $window.alert(greeting);
        $window.ga('send', 'event', 'alert box event', 'click', greeting)
      };
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="greeting" aria-label="greeting" />
  <button ng-click="doGreeting(greeting)">ALERT</button>
</div>
</body>
```

This example is using Angular's documentation example.

Comment: it gives me an error Expected identifier, string or number